# Installed GitLab failed at config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

I was trying to install GitLab using

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

It in the "Configure it" section at

## Copy the example Rack attack config

sudo -u git -H cp config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example config/initializers/rack_attack.rb

with the error

cp: cannot stat `config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example': No such file or directory

Comment: Make sure you are in your app's directory when running the command (because it is using a relative path)

Comment: ls: cannot access /home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Rack attack only exists on gitlab 6.2-stable. So before running this command make sure you are on the proper branch. To do so type "git checkout 6-2-stable" on the root of the repository.